# Less Memory-intense way of copying tables & renaming columns in sqlite/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have found a very nice way to:

1. read a table from a sql database
2. rename the columns with a dict (read from a yaml file)
3. rewrite the table to another database

The only problem is, that as the table becomes bigger(10col x several million rows), reading the table into a pandas is so memory-intensive, that it causes the process to be killed.

There must be an easier way. I looked at alter table statements but they seem to be very complicated as well& will not do the copying in another db. Any ideas on how to do the same operation without using this much memory. Feeling like pandas are a crutch I use due to my bad sql.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
def translate2generic(sourcedb, targetdb, sourcetable,
                      targettable, toberenamed):
    """Change table's column names to fit generic api keys.

    :param: Path to source db
    :param: Path to target db
    :param: Name of table to be translated in source
    :param: Name of the newly to be created table in targetdb
    :param: dictionary of translations
    :return: New column names in target db
    """
    sourceconn = sqlite3.connect(sourcedb)
    targetconn = sqlite3.connect(targetdb)
    table = pd.read_sql_query('select * from ' + sourcetable, sourceconn) #this is the line causing the crash

    # read dict in the format {"oldcol1name": "newcol1name", "oldcol2name": "newcol2name"}
    rename = {v: k for k, v in toberenamed.items()} 


    # rename columns
    generic_table = table.rename(columns=rename)

    # Write table to new database
    generic_table.to_sql(targettable, targetconn, if_exists="replace")
    targetconn.close()
    sourceconn.close()
```

I've looked also at solutions such as [this one](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/04/sqlite-rename-a-column.html) but they suppose you know the type of the columns.

An elegant solution would be very much appreciated.

Edit: I know there is a method in sqlite since the September release 3.25.0, but I am stuck with version 2.6.0

Comment: Recent versions of sqlite let you rename columns directly.

Comment: You can also copy data between database files directly in sqlite. Open one file, `ATTACH` the other and use the `SELECT ... FROM` version of `INSERT` or `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @Shawn: Thanks. I know about the recent version of sqlite, but I am stuck with 2.6.0.

Comment: Sqlite 2.6.0 was released *sixteen years* ago. Why in the world are you still using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comments...

If you have a table in foo.db and want to copy that table's data to a new table in bar.db with different column names:

```
$ sqlite3 foo.db
sqlite> ATTACH 'bar.db' AS bar;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE bar.newtable(newcolumn1, newcolumn2);
sqlite> INSERT INTO bar.newtable SELECT oldcolumn1, oldcolumn2 FROM main.oldtable;
```

Comment: seems to be what I was looking for. main.oldtable = foo.oldtable? And this is from the commandline? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: The first database opened in a connection is given the schema name "main". If other files are attached you have to specify a different name for each, but afaik there's no way to change the main name. And yes, the example uses the command line sqlite3 shell program. (Which probably isn't backwards compatible with sqlite 2...)